# How to calculate a measure/column using a join condition in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables, Project table and User table. I have to fetch the name of the project manager using DAX exp.

Below is the table structure:

```
Project table

Project_ID    Name           Manager_Id       

1                  Aladeen       10

2                  Pointy           2



User table

User_ID       Name 

1                 Boss

2                 Baby

10               Musk
```

Now, I have to create to measure/column in the Project table with DAX which gives me the names of users from the second table.

P.S. Both the tables are in direct query mode.

Desired output-

Project table

```
Project_ID    Name           Manager_Id       Project_Manager

1             Aladeen          10                     Musk

2             Pointy           2                      Baby
```

How can I achieve this in DAX? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use direct query, but this should work.

```
UserName = calculate( max('User Table'[Name]), TREATAS('Project Table'[Manager_Id]       ,'User Table'[Id]) )
```

https://dax.guide/treatas/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the direct query in Power BI, but if you have two separate tables and you can define the relationship between them, then it will work with your data.

1. Create a relationship between *Project Table* and *User Table* by dragging the column *Manager_Id* to *User_ID* in **Model View** of Power BI

[image: Relationship between two tables]

2. Create a new calculated column wwith following DAX:

   ```
    Project_Manager = RELATED('User Table'[Name])
   ```

   This will give you a new column in the Project table with the manager name corresponding to the Manager_Id

[image: Output]